# OnTap listener implementation

Tags: android, tap

I have a doubt that is on tap listener implemented on a particular button, or image view or view? because the sites which I surfed only shows for the whole layout and I want my action to be performed on the tapping of a view. please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Any view can be setup with an `onClickListener()` which is part of the view class. The easiest way to do it is when you setup the references to your view in the `onCreate()` method. Here is an example for a image view:

```
ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewByID(R.id.example);
iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // Do what you need to do on click
        ....
    }
});
```

---

UPDATE: DOUBLE TAP

Here is a sample activity which implements basic double tap detection on an image view:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class DoubleTapActivity extends Activity {
    //Set the double tap delay in milliseconds
    protected static final long DOUBLE_CLICK_MAX_DELAY = 1000L;
    private ImageView iView;
    private long thisTime = 0;
    private long prevTime = 0;
    private boolean firstTap = true;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        iView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.iView);
        iView.setOnTouchListener( new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(firstTap){
                    thisTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
                    firstTap = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    prevTime = thisTime;
                    thisTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

                    //Check that thisTime is greater than prevTime
                    //just incase system clock reset to zero
                    if(thisTime > prevTime){

                        //Check if times are within our max delay
                        if((thisTime - prevTime) <= DOUBLE_CLICK_MAX_DELAY){

                            //We have detected a double tap!
                            Toast.makeText(DoubleTapActivity.this, "DOUBLE TAP DETECTED!!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            //PUT YOUR LOGIC HERE!!!!

                        }
                        else 
                        {
                            //Otherwise Reset firstTap
                            firstTap = true;
                        }
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        firstTap = true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: yes i know this code Kenny but what i m asking can DOUBLE TAP LISTENER be implemented on a particular view or for a whole screen. i am making a project in which i have to take action on the tap of only a view not the whole screen.

Comment: You never mentioned double tap anywhere in your question! But I've expanded my answer to show you one possible way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Mostly to sense tap event you have to implement `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener` in your Activity. You can perform action by using `onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e)` method of `GestureDetector.OnGestureListener`.

Generally for Button control, we use like

`myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {});`

or other clickListners and tap events are used for ImageView or any other customviews.

Answer (score 1):

Add `android:onClick="tapEvent"` in your layout which you want to take the click. By changing the `MAX_TAP_COUNT` value, you can use any number of taps.

```
private long thisTime = 0;
private long prevTime = 0;
private int tapCount = 0;
private static  final int MAX_TAP_COUNT = 5;
protected static final long DOUBLE_CLICK_MAX_DELAY = 500;


public void tapEvent(View v){

    if (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() > thisTime) {
        if ((SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - thisTime) > DOUBLE_CLICK_MAX_DELAY * MAX_TAP_COUNT) {
            Log.d(TAG, "touch event " + "resetting tapCount = 0");
            tapCount = 0;
        }
        if (tapCount()) {
           //DO YOUR LOGIC HERE
        }
    }
}

private Boolean tapCount(){

    if (tapCount == 0) {
        thisTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        tapCount++;
    } else if (tapCount < (MAX_TAP_COUNT-1)) {
        tapCount++;
    } else {
        prevTime = thisTime;
        thisTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        //just incase system clock reset to zero
        if (thisTime > prevTime) {

            //Check if times are within our max delay
            if ((thisTime - prevTime) <= DOUBLE_CLICK_MAX_DELAY * MAX_TAP_COUNT) {
                //We have detected a multiple continuous tap!
                //Once receive multiple tap, reset tap count to zero for consider next tap as new start
                tapCount = 0;
                return true;
            } else {
                //Otherwise Reset tapCount
                tapCount = 0;
            }
        } else {
            tapCount = 0;
        }
    }
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

    // on action down do your work...
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: You should add an explanation about your answer because it will help the author easy to understand.