# Double Tap event in an Activity

Tags: android

I have an activity that implements onGestureListener . How to do i detect the double tap events in the same activity? Is it possible to recognise a double tap event in an activity?

it also doesnt recognise a long press ? Any help with that?

Comment: This is what you could have found on this site and answers your question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716224/ontap-listener-implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716224/ontap-listener-implementation)

Comment: i've done it using timers in the onTouch method. not sure if thats something you'd be interested in.

Comment: Oh you say like you timed the touch event for 1560ms huh?

Comment: No i already saw that! :D Thanks anyways! I wanted it to work along with Gesture Detector!

Comment: @user1922235 could update your question so that the people who comes in later can have a clear map :)

Comment: yeah something like that. its not ideal, i know, but its a bit difficult to implement double tap unless you're willing to spend a lot of time. double tap is not a prescribed behaviour though- android users rarely double tap stuff.

Comment: Yeah i think i'd be interested in urs because i have this gestureoverlay thingy n it doesnt work :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**onDoubleTap** function Use specific element, like an **ImageView** id, is '*selectedImage*' & run this function name is '*selectImage()*' full code:

```
findViewById(R.id.selectdImage).setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(MainActivity.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDoubleTap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                selectImage(nView);
                return super.onDoubleTap(e);
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
                Log.d("onSingleTapConfirmed", "onSingleTap");
                return false;
            }
        });

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 9):

`GestureDetector` allows you to specify `OnDoubleTapListener` as well as `OnGestureListener`. The only thing you need to do is implement `OnDoubleTapListener` and override its `onDoubleTap` method.

Also you can use `SimpleOnGestureListener` and override only what you want.

```
final Context context = this;
final GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener listener = new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onDoubleTap", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "onLongPress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
};

final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(listener);

detector.setOnDoubleTapListener(listener);
detector.setIsLongpressEnabled(true);

getWindow().getDecorView().setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
        return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

For any view you can do like this

```
   ivPost.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            private GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(ActivityName.this, new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
                    Log.d("TEST", "onDoubleTap");
                    return super.onDoubleTap(e);
                }
                @Override
                public boolean onSingleTapConfirmed(MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.d("TEST", "onSingleTap");
                    return false;
                }
            });

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
                return true;
            }


        });
```